# Popovers via Event Propagation in JS

Tags: javascript, events, dom

I’m trying to create a popover in React (although I don’t think it’s React specific). To dismiss the popover, by clicking outside, I’m adding a click event listener to `document.body`, which will close the popover, and another event listener to the top-most node of the popover, which stops the event propagating (so it won’t reach the body).

Am I doing something wrong in my code, or is my method completely off? What I see is (if I don’t close the popover) that the body event gets triggered first, then the popover click event.

```
var Popover = React.createClass({
    componentWillMount() {
        document.body.addEventListener('click', this.handleDocumentClick);
    },
    componentWillUnmount() {
        document.body.removeEventListener('click', this.handleDocumentClick);
    },
    handleDocumentClick(e) {
        console.log('triggered from document document', e);
        this.props.onClose();
    },
    handleSelfClick(e) {
        console.log('triggered from popover', e);
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    },
    render() {
        var { top, left, width } = this.props;

        return (
            <div key={ `${top}:${left}` } className='popover top' style={{ top, left, width }} onClick={ this.handleSelfClick }>
                <div className='popover-arrow-top' style={{ left }} />
                <div className='popover-content'>
                    { this.props.children }
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Edit, removed onClick from the popover element, just recursively searched the parent elements to check for the current node.

```
componentWillMount() {
    document.addEventListener('click', this.handleDocumentClick);
},
componentWillUnmount() {
    document.removeEventListener('click', this.handleDocumentClick);
},
handleDocumentClick(e) {
    var self = this.getDOMNode();
    var { onClose } = this.props;

    (function searchParent (currentTarget) {
        if (!currentTarget) {
            onClose(); // Clicked body
        } else if (currentTarget !== self) {
            searchParent(currentTarget.parentNode);
        } // else was in popover, stop iteration
    })(e.target);
}, ...
```

Comment: Try just `document.addEventListener` instead

Comment: No luck with that. Fixed now though. Thanks anyway!